# What are transducers good for other than optimization and helping language/API designers?

Tags: transducer

After watching Rich Hickey's [talk on transducers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII), my understanding is that they can

1. greatly optimize performance of compositions of reducers (by removing the need for intermediate sequence representations)
2. assist a language/API designer in getting reducers 'for free' over all of their sequences/iterables/streams/etc as long as they are implemented once as a transducer.

Beyond these advantages (which may not be relevant for many) are there any other benefits to coding with transducers?

Answer (score 0):

Transducers allow you to write transformation function without caring about the data structure. So the same map, filter, whatever for lists, sequences, channels, parralells.

See e.g. https://github.com/matthiasn/talk-transcripts/blob/master/Hickey_Rich/Transducers/00.43.52.jpg

Comment: Yes. I asked "What are transducers good for OTHER than optimization and helping language/API designers?" Like, if performance is not an issue, and I'm not creating a language or API, do I need to care?